# get/set logical working directory from C

Tags: c, unix, symlink, working-directory

I have a symbolic link /home/me/symlink -> /home/me/realdir
when I try to getcwd in the directory /home/me/symlink I get /home/me/realdir with the following program:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    char path[PATH_MAX];
    getcwd(path, PATH_MAX);
    printf("path %s\n", path);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to get the directory /home/me/symlink? And, is there a way to set the current working directory to a symlinked directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I. No ([docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html))
:

> The pathname shall contain no components that are dot or dot-dot, or are symbolic links.

However, there's a workaround:

```
char *cwd = getenv("PWD");
```

II. Yes ([docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html))
:

```
chdir("/path/to/newcwd");
```